# export to excel for dynamic columns with header

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

In my another application i have one datatable with dynamic columns. My code should export the datatable content into excel format. The code i have is working for datatable with fixed number of columns. But it is not bringing the header row if it is in dynamic columns. I have gone through more sites, they suggested to have dummy column with  tag. I tried with that also. But not able to bring header in excel. Other excel contents are displayed properly.

The code i have is:

Xhtml code:

```
<p:dataTable id="rosterviewtab" var="data" value="#{dtRosterView.rostertab}" >

    <p:columnGroup type="header">

        <p:row>
            <p:column headerText="" />

    <p:column style="display:none">
            <f:facet name="header"> #{dtRosterView.dates}   </f:facet>
    </p:column>

            <ui:repeat value="#{dtRosterView.dates}" var="dates">
               <p:column headerText="#{dates}" exportable="false" />                
            </ui:repeat>
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>   

      <p:column> 
        <h:outputText value="#{data.slot_noresources}" />
      </p:column>    

     <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{data.datecol1}" />
    </p:column>     

     <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{data.datecol2}" />
    </p:column> 

    </p:dataTable>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
    <p:commandButton value="Export To Excel" style="font-size:11px;width:120px;height:40px" immediate="true" ajax="false" >          
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="rosterviewtab" fileName="RosterView" postProcessor="#{dtRosterView.postProcessXLS}" update="@form"  />
    </p:commandButton>
```

and in my Bean class:

```
public void postProcessXLS(Object document) 
{     HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;        
      HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
     for (Row row : sheet) {            
          for (Cell cell : row) {   
       System.out.println("cell value -->"+ cell.getStringCellValue());
       cell.setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue().toUpperCase());                
        }       
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, I used a p:fileDownload instead and implemented it like this :
in the xhtml:

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false">
     <p:graphicImage value="#{exportType.icon}" title="#{exportType.firstLangName}"/>
     <p:fileDownload value="#{customStatementBean.makeExportFile(exportType.exportTypeId)}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

and in the bean :

```
    public StreamedContent makeExportFile(Long exportTypeId) {
        InputStream stream;
        try {
            stream = customStatementService.getExportFileInputStream(customStatementSO, customStatementResult, exportTypeId, getCurrentLanguage().toLowerCase());
        } catch (SabaBusinessException e) {
            saveError(e);
            return null;
        }
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, getContentType(exportTypeId), customStatementService.makeFileName(customStatementSO, exportTypeId), "UTF-8");
    }
```

and of course in the customStatementService.getExportFileInputStream I\ve created the excel file using POI as I needed.

the dependency I am using for poi in my pom.xml is like this :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there any dependencies to use filedownload..Since in my application fileupload functionality is there and we faced lot of dependency issues in that. Still we are not able to do upload . if possible can you please post full source.

Comment: sorry for my late response, I've edited the answer to provide the extra information you've asked for. of course the POI is needed for excel, not using p:fileDownload

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using the below code.

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;        
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
    /*HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(1);
    HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();        
    for(int i=0; i < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();i++) {  
        HSSFCell cell = header.getCell(i);  

        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);  
    }  */
    HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
    //HSSFCell r1c1 = row1.createCell(1);
    //r1c1.setCellValue("dates");
    int columval = 1;
    for(int d=0; d<dates.size();d++)
    {
        System.out.println("dates-->"+dates.get(d).toString());
        HSSFCell r1c1 = row1.createCell(columval);
        r1c1.setCellValue(dates.get(d).toString());
        columval +=1;
    }
    for (Row row : sheet) {            
        for (Cell cell : row) {   
            System.out.println("cell value -->"+ cell.getStringCellValue());
            cell.setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue().toUpperCase());                

            }       
        }
```